# Idea behind Search By Tag in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a `Search by tags` functionality using `react` as it shown in the picture below :

[image]

***The problem***

I am not able to do so because of `props drilling` issue and I am struggling mostly with it, because I sometimes need to send data from `child` component to the `parent` component even if the `parent` component is further than the `child` component where the data will be sent from with many children component that they don't need these data.

**Please note:** I am still unsuccessfully able to move data from `child` to another  `child` that lives above it to the targeted `parent` component.

The thing is I don't want to use other solutions like `REDUX` or `ContextAPI`

Please check the code provided below or **codesandbox** whichever version you like.

**codesandbox** -> https://codesandbox.io/s/red-cloud-uu74k

All I want is to have a logical thinking way of how I could possibly move data from `Child` to `parent`

```js
// PARENT COMPONENT

import "./App.css";
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useFetch from "./hooks/useFetch";
import Person from "./components/Person";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import SearchByTags from "./components/SearchByTags";

function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [tagsInput, setTagsInput] = useState("");

  const complete = useFetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students");

  const students = complete?.data?.students;
  students?.forEach((student) => {
    Object.assign(student, { tags: [] });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setPeople(students);
  }, [students]);

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const filteredNames = people?.filter((p) => {
    return (p.firstName + p.lastName)
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(inputValue.toLowerCase());
  });

  // const filteredTags = people?.filter((p) => {
  //   p.tags.forEach((t) => {
  //     return t.toLowerCase().includes(tagsInput.toLowerCase());
  //   });
  // });

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleInputTag = (e) => {
    setTagsInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="search">
          <Search handleInput={handleInput} />
        </div>
        <div className="search">
          <SearchByTags handleInput={handleInputTag} />
        </div>
        {/* Conditional Rendering
          - Default Render
          - Render By Name
          - Render By Tag
          - Render By Name & Tag        
        */}
        {filteredNames?.map((person) => (
          <Person key={person.id} person={person} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


// CHILD COMPONENT 

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Image from "./Image";
import Heading from "./Heading";
import StudentsInfo from "./StudentsInfo";
import Average from "./Average";
import Button from "./Button";
import Grade from "./Grade";
import Tag from "./Tag";

function Person({ person }) {
  const [grades, setGrades] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setGrades(!grades);
  };

  return (
    <div key={person.id} className="profile">
      <div>
        <Image picture={person.pic} name={person.firstName} />
      </div>
      <div className="info">
        <Heading firstName={person.firstName} lastName={person.lastName} />
        <StudentsInfo
          email={person.email}
          company={person.company}
          skill={person.skill}
        />
        <Average person={person} />
        {grades ? <Grade grades={person.grades} /> : ""}
        <Tag />
      </div>
      <div className="buttonDiv">
        <Button handleClick={handleClick} grades={grades} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Person;

// Another Child Component lives in Person Component

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function Tag(props) {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const addTags = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
      setTags([...tags, e.target.value]);
      e.target.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="tagsDiv">
      <ul>
        {tags.map((tag, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <span>{tag}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        onKeyUp={addTags}
        type="search"
        className="searchInput tag"
        placeholder="Add a tag"
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tag;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use something like Context API? This sounds like a case of you know there are tools to solve an issue but you want to work around not using them the hard way

Comment: @charlietfl How to do so with 'useContext' ?